# Acessing value of variable in callign method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, eval

I am learning in javascript and i want to solve this:

```
var text = "element1";
function OpenOrClose (text){
CKEDITOR.instances.text.getData();
}
```

I just want to replace text in calling method in function by value of variable text (in this case element1). I also read something about eval('text') and window['text'], but when i tryed to use it like this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.eval('text').getData();
```

It wasn't work.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I've seen some creative uses of *eval*, but that one is new to me. You could have done `eval('CKEDITOR.instances.' + text + '.getData()');` but *please* don't! ;-) You will be in much trouble if *text* doesn't return a valid identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes = items etc.

```
CKEDITOR.instances[text].getData();
```